# Есть как range в dart

Tags: dart

в питоне range реализуется просто
for i in range(1, 10) # Например
А есть такой синтаксис в dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { print(i); }
```

Где `int i = 0` это начало ранга. А `i < 10` условие конца ранга.

Comment: Про этот синтаксис я знаю. А вот просто range нету в dart? Спасибо

Comment: Нет, и он не нужен...

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. А можно с вами связаться где-нибудь, чтоб задавать вопросы напрямую?