# Списочное выражение в dart

Tags: dart

Вот в питоне можно создать список вот так: `lst = [i for i in range(10)]`

А в dart можно ли так сделать? (в 1 строку)

Comment: [дубликат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1302569/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-range-%d0%b2-dart)

Comment: Ну как бы нет. Именно при создании

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У списков есть именованный конструктор [generate](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.generate.html):

```dart
List<int>.generate(10, (int index) => index)
```

Comment: Спасибо
А можно, пожалуйста, выйти с вами на связь? В вк или телеграмм?